# Creating PDFs in a commercial application, how to license?

Tags: .net, licensing

I'm working on a commercial project, a small part of this project will be creating reports and writing the report to a PDF. How would you recommend I do this? I'm only aware of open source projects such as itextsharp.sourceforge.net but I'm guessing I can't use this commercially. What are my options? Anyone done this?

PS Using .Net to develop.

Thanks
S

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using .Net, you can use a local rdlc report (rather than having to install reporting services.) and use the report viewer to export as a pdf.

Basically, just build the report and call ReportViewer.LocalReport.Render() specifying "PDF" for the format.

I've done it for several projects - works great.

Answer (score 1):

If you are feeling particularly masochistic [the adobe PDF format specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html) is available.

Answer (score 0):

**SQL Server Reporting Services** can generate reports to PDF. Its very similar to Crystal Reports and its a part of SQL Server, so no extra cost there.  And its very easy to implement.

Comment: You mean "it's a part of SQL Server". Normally I wouldn't nitpick this, but "[it's] apart..." actually means the opposite!

Answer (score 0):

Warning: I am not a lawyer!

Actually, iTextSharp is LGPL so, if I understand that license correctly, you can use it in a closed-source application without any problem (please read the license to make sure, though).  I think with LGPL all you'd have to do is include the license from iTextSharp with your product.  If you are developing a for-pay service then I don't think you have any obligation (legally) to do anything extra.

Comment: You're right that you also need to include the LGPL license text. LGPL also requires isolation of the LGPL'ed component, typically by using a shared library, and an offer for source code. LGPL does not exclude for-profit projects.

Answer (score 0):

XML + XSLT + nFOP = PDF

last time i checked nFOP needed J# runtime, url: http://sourceforge.net/projects/nfop/

Make sure to check the T&C of license.

K